# FreeBSD make error File 5.19 supports only version 12 magic files. /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc is version 8

Tags: makefile, freebsd, proftpd

I'm having trouble reinstalling ProFTPD on a FreeBSD 10.1 setup. The server is newly upgraded from 10.0 to 10.1. When I start the make install clean process, these warnings first shows on screen.

```
===>  proftpd-1.3.5_4 depends on shared library: libpcre.so
/usr/share/misc/magic, 93: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `, %ld pages'
...
/usr/share/misc/magic, 15118: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/misc/magic, 15609: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
file: File 5.19 supports only version 12 magic files. `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc' is   version 8
[: =: unexpected operator
- not found
```

And after i while, the make process stops with this error:

```
/bin/ln -s libpcre.so.1 /usr/ports/devel/pcre/work/stage/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.3
====> Compressing man pages (compress-man)
===>  Installing for pcre-8.35_2
===>  Checking if pcre already installed
===>  pcre-8.35_2 is already installed
You may wish to ``make deinstall'' and install this port again
by ``make reinstall'' to upgrade it properly.
If you really wish to overwrite the old port of pcre
without deleting it first, set the variable "FORCE_PKG_REGISTER"
in your environment or the "make install" command line.
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make[3]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/pcre
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[2]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/pcre
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/ftp/proftpd
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/ftp/proftpd
```

Seems that the file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc is of a wrong version?
This might happens when I was upgrading from 10.0-RELEASE-p12 to 10.1-RELESE-p1?

If i run make install clean of the ProFTP port, and disable support for pcre, the process and install is successful.
But I believe that something is still broken?

My programming skills are limited, and also this level of error.
Please let me know if you have any ideas,

Thanks,

Comment: This question is off-topic here. It belongs to the [Super User site](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: `[: =: unexpected operator` is a shell syntax error. Something is wrong in whatever script is causing that. `- not found` is probably related to that first error (hopefully) but means something else about the script is wrong. You need to find out what version of `file` you are supposed to have and what version magic file at this point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, proftpd 1.3.5 is available as a binary package, it's much simpler to install it that way (pkg install proftpd).

Second - at first it looked like a port bug; as Etan said, there is a shell syntax error (something like '[ x == y ]' instead of '[ x = y ]'); those are common, and ports contain patches to fix those.  However, there is a binary package, and packages are built from ports ("make package"), so port obviously does work on package build machines.  So it's probably something specific to your environment.

If you really want to build from ports, try this: first, reinstall pcre.  For some reason it had to be rebuilt, but failed to install, because it's already installed.  So, "cd /usr/ports/*/pcre  && make clean all deinstall reinstall".  That should get rid of the second error.  Then go back to "../*/proftpd" and see how far it goes.

But really, I'd try packages first.  They have nothing in common with old pkg_add system, and are *really* nice.

Answer (score 1):

freebsd-update diff for FreeBSD-SA-14:28.file seems wrong, and it breaks file(1).

Therefore simply `pkg install file` will be a workaround.